# Extension of Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

/*

- @Author: Programmer name
- @Date: 2021-11-27 09:54:24
- @LastEditTime: 2021-12-14 20:10:19
- @LastEditors: Please set LastEditors
- @Description: The first try of calculator for 2 inputs only using C++ programming language for school project.
- @FilePath: /SRC Code/calculator1.cpp
  */

What Extension gives this format automatically for any code we wrote on it.
The extension name.

Comment: I think you can create your own template

Comment: Give a try to 'git history'